# Python search in child elements

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have a XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Orders>
    <Order>
        <Key>30611-897647</Key>
        <Date>2021.06.25 05:04:18</Date>
        <DateMod>2021.06.25 16:03:19</DateMod>
        <Lang>hu</Lang>
        <Customer>
            <Email><![CDATA[xxxx@gmail.com]]></Email>
            <Username><![CDATA[xxxx@gmail.com]]></Username>
            <Contact>
                <Name><![CDATA[Some_One]]></Name>
                <Phone><![CDATA[]]></Phone>
                <Mobile><![CDATA[+36999999]]></Mobile>
                <Lang>hu</Lang>
            </Contact>
         </Customer>
    </Order>
</Order>
```

and so on

I can print the Order data:
Key, Date, DateMod, and Lang like this

```
for x in root[0]:
    print(x.tag,x.text)
```

How can I search in Customer? To print out Email,username etc.

Comment: What library do you use to parse the XML?

Comment: xml.etree.ElementTree

Comment: I see! I mostly use [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html) because it's supposedly faster, but the API seems to be the same in this case (see my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need all the `Customer` elements:

```
for customer in root.iter('Customer'):
    for elem in customer:
        print(elem.tag, elem.text)
```